# How can I show the oldest and newest image with ExifTool in Windows?

Tags: file-management, exiftool, windows-7, date

Is there any way to show the name of the oldest and the newest image in the current folder with ExifTool, based on the shooting date?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what OS you're using, but in a Windows Powershell you could do something like this:

`exiftool -filename -fileorder datetimeoriginal DIR | select -first 2 -last 4`

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that, Windows 7 it is. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

> (i.e. sort by shooting date and show oldest and newest images' name of file)

?  then look at the top and bottom entries in the sort.

Comment: I cannot. There are too many images and the cmd's buffer is not that large.

Comment: @ldigas, make it bigger :)